# How i can set distance (space) between 2 buttons in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]I added 2 buttons in my flutter app, but distance between them is too big, because of this my TextField is too small. Here is the example of my code

```
TextField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Type message')),
RaisedButton(
   child: Icon(Icons.attach_file),
   color: Colors.white,
   shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide.none),
   onPressed: () {
   BottomSheet(context);
   }),
RaisedButton(
   child: Icon(Icons.send),
   color: Colors.white,
   shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide.none),
   onPressed: () => null)
```

p.s Here is the screen, i want to decrease distance between 2 buttons and place 'send' button to the right bottom corner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap them in a row, and use expanded widgets with flex, to detirmine how much space they can take up.

```
Row (children: [
Expanded(flex:5, 
child: TextField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Type message'))),
SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of.(context)size.width*0.15, 
child:RaisedButton(
   child: Icon(Icons.attach_file),
   color: Colors.white,
   shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide.none),
   onPressed: () {
   BottomSheet(context);
   })),
SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of.(context)size.width*0.15,
child:RaisedButton(
   child: Icon(Icons.send),
   color: Colors.white,
   shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide.none),
   onPressed: () => null))
])
```

Comment: I already used expanded on all Container, anyway i tried to add like u said, but it only moves my text field or space between second button and safe area. Space between first and second button didn't change

Comment: Manipulate the flex factor as you want. you didn't post a picture of how you want it to look.

Comment: i added picture, i hope this helps

Comment: I modified my answer, use media query, and set the width to as much as you'd like. the 0.15 means 15% of the allowed with in the screen's space.

Comment: u forgot . after (context) but it helped. thank u a lot

Comment: Oh yes, definitely don't forget the dot, you're most welcome! Happy coding.